# cancel non renewable subscription from the application

Tags: ios, swift

How to cancel the non-renewable subscription from the App.

[image]

Comment: It's non-renewable so you don't need to cancel it.  Once they have purchased it they need to purchase it again at the end of the period.

Comment: Got it, Thanks Sir.

Comment: There is no way to cancel the non renewal subscription, only you can restore purchase if there is exist, or you can validate by its receipt, If you want know how to validate receipt please ask another question

To get idea for receipt validation please follow this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15540429/7500742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cancel the non renewal subscription, only you can restore purchase if there is exist, or you can validate by its receipt, If you want know how to validate receipt please ask another question

To get idea for receipt validation please follow this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15540429/7500742

Answer (score 3):

You can’t cancel what user already bought for money. Non renewable subscription withdraw money only once.